# Do power plants even follow law of conservation of energy

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electricity, energy-conservation

Correct me if i am wrong but all circuits must follow the law of conservation of energy.
And the energy is supplied by the action of source to create a potential difference by moving charges against electric field
In a battery the energy of chemical reactions that create potential difference is equal to the energy used so the spin of an electric generator must have enough energy to equal it's usage in multiple homes.
So all of heat energy that get's used in multiple homes and rotating fans they all get singled out by a spinning conductor in a magnetic field?
Ik this might be stupid but to me it seems sorta impossible

Comment: the "spinning conductor in a magnetic field" is spinning because something else is supplying the energy needed for it to continue spinning.

Answer (score 2):

Power plants live and die by those rules. Think of a power plant as a machine that turns one kind of energy into another. A coal-fired plant turns heat from burning coal into boiling-hot water, making steam. the thermal energy in the high-pressure steam spins the turbine, converting it into mechanical power which is used to spin a generator which converts the mechanical power into electricity.

Energy conservation is present at every step in this process.

Answer (score 0):

In electric power plants, high pressure steam turns a turbo-generator to generate 60 Hz A/C current (in the U.S).  That turbo-generator has a tachometer on it, continuously measuring the rpm, which should be 3600 rpm at all times.  This data goes to a control scheme that manipulates the steam valve to the turbo-generator.  If the rpm drops below 3600 rpm by a small amount, it means that the demand is starting to exceed supply, and the control scheme responds by slightly opening the steam valve in order to send more steam to the turbo-generator.  If the rpm rises above 3600 rpm by a small amount, the opposite action is taken. This means that electricity generation is matched with electricity demand at all times, unless the demand exceeds the maximum generating capacity of the equipment.  Also note that as Niels Nielsen states, energy conservation takes place at all times.